# Java constructor calling and changing values of parent class instance variables

Tags: java, constructor, this, super

```
public class Pparent{
    int p;
}

public class Raw1 extends Pparent {
    int c;
    Raw1(int c, int p){
        this.c = c;
        this.p = p;//
        System.out.println(this.p);
        System.out.println(this.c);
        System.out.println(super.p);
        //super.p = p;//
        System.out.println(this.p);
    // so can we say that only reference of parent class is getting inside child class
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Raw1 rrr = new Raw1(1,20);
        Pparent ppp = new Pparent();
        System.out.println(ppp.p);
        System.out.println(rrr.p);

    }

}
```

here in third line when i am printing the value of super.p variable, it prints as 20. but i havent initialize the value of super.p , i just have initialized the value of this.p, so i should get value as 0 but i am getting value as 20. can anybody please explain how!!!1

Comment: this.p is super.p

Answer (score 1):

```
this.p = p;
```

initializes the value of `Pparent` class's `p` instance variable, since the child class `Raw1` has no `p` instance variable that hides the parent class variable, and the parent class variable is accessible by the child class, since it's package private by default.

If you change the access of the `p` variable to `private`, your code will not pass compilation.

Comment: As you are saying this.p = p initialises value of Pparent variable, but when i am printing ppp.p in main method l, it is giving me output as 0, if you are right then it should give us ans as 20

Comment: @AnujPatel `ppp` and `rrr` are referencing different objects. Only for the object referenced by `rrr` you initialized `p` to 20.

Answer (score 0):

Your p attribute has default access level. So when you call child constructor you set property directly.

Comment: But when i am printing ppp.p in main that time it is giving me answer as 0, if you are true then answer must be 20

Comment: `rrr` and `ppp` are 2 different instances. So, each having its own `this.p`. `rrr` is inheriting the `p` property of its superclass, and `ppp` is having its own `p`. This is the effect of inheritance. Every `Raw1` instance is also a `Pparent`.